# How do I know which alias contains the certificate and private key in a Java keystore?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, jks

I need to extract our SSL certificate and private key from our JKS keystore and send it to a third party vendor we are interfacing with.  The person who created the keystore and imported the cert is no longer with the company, so I don't know which alias I specifically need to use.

Would the certificate and private key be extracted from the same alias?  I have 5 aliases in my keystore.  3 are dated 2010, 2 are dated 2012.  The 2012 aliases have entry types of PrivateKeyEntry and trustedCertEntry.  The 3 dated 2010 are trustedCertEntry.  All 5 are within valid date ranges indicating none are expired.

My understanding is that the PrivateKeyEntry contains the private key and the certificate chain?  Does this mean that both the certificate and private key should be extracted from the same alias?

I don't have a lot of room for error here and want to make sure I fully understand what I'm exporting and sending off.

Comment: "I need to extract our SSL certificate and private key from our JKS keystore and send it to a third party vendor we are interfacing with.". There is something seriously wrong here. Your private key is a precious security resource. The instant you send it anywhere it is compromised and can no longer be used for the purpose it was intended for. If an external vendor is asking for your private key it is *prima facie* evidence of gross incompetence. Let the vendor generate his own keys, for whatever purpose, e.g. testing. Please **do not underestimate** the seriousness of what you propose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias used for Certificate does not have to correspond to the Private Key. So, you would have to take your chances.

**Edit:**

I haven't really tried this out. But it really shouldn't matter because a Certificate depends on the Public-Private Key. Password given in the keystore are just a way to secure them and giving it to only a trusted user. So, I would suggest you to generate the certificate and compare them with the other one's using the getEncoded method. This would give you the binaries and you could compare them.

Comment: Good to know, thank you.  The keystore was obtained from our JBoss config.  Unfortunately, I didn't see anything in there that indicated which alias was used.  The keytool successfully exported a certificate from the PrivateKeyEntry, so I'm going to have to trust that is correct for now.

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted since you are right and there is technically no way to know, so it's on me to figure that out.

A final question, (if it's against etiquette, I'll make a new post): In this case, the Private Key and Certificate were exported from the same alias.  When I export the private key to a new keystore (PKCS), does changing the password before sending it off have any bearing on the previously exported certificate?  Ex: I export the cert to a file, then export the private key to a PKCS P12 file with a new password that does not match the old keystore.

Comment: @framauro13: Updated the answer take a look. Also, let me know the resolution of the issue

Comment: The alias used for a certificate *does* have to correspond to the alias used when generating the private key whose public key it encapsulates.So all you have to do is list the aliases for the key entries, and typically there will only be one. However there is something grossly wrong with the whole question.